# Threading with Bottle.py Server

Tags: python, multithreading, bottle

I'm having an issue with threading that I can't solve in any way I've tried. I searched in StackOverflow too, but all I could find was cases that didn't apply to me, or explanations that I didn't understand.

I'm trying to build an app with BottlePy, and one of the features I want requires a function to run in background. For this, I'm trying to make it run in a thread. However, when I start the thread, it runs **twice**.

I've read in some places that it would be possible to check if the function was in the main script or in a module using `if __name__ == '__main__':`, however I'm not able to do this, since `__name__` is always returning the name of the module.

Below is an example of what I'm doing right now.

The main script:

```
# main.py
from MyClass import *
from bottle import *

arg = something

myObject = Myclass(arg1)

app = Bottle()
app.run('''bottle args''')
```

The class:

```
# MyClass.py
import threading
import time

class MyClass:
    def check_list(self, theList, arg1):
        a_list = something()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.check_list(a_list, arg1)

    def __init__(self, arg1):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            self.a_list = arg.returnAList()
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.check_list, args=(a_list, arg1))
```

So what I intend here is to have *check_list* running in a thread all the time, doing something and waiting some seconds to run again. All this so I can have the list updated, and be able to read it with the main script.

Can you explain to me what I'm doing wrong, why the thread is running twice, and how can I avoid this?

Comment: You're creating a second thread in `check_list`? What happens if you remove `time.sleep(5)` and the line after ? Also, you don't need to put `if __name__ ...`, at least not here.

Comment: Now that you mention it... yes, that doesn't seem right. However, even when not creating a new thread in the end of the function it gets called twice. If I just do 'self.check_time(plans, db_handler)' it still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: In your edited code, you have `check_list` calling `check_list`, typo ?

Comment: It is supposed to get called again, no? How else would it run every x seconds? I was creating a thread before, now I'm calling it again directly, without creating a thread.

Comment: How do you know the thread is running twice? What do you observe? (Also, note that Python doesn't optimize tail recursion, so your function calling itself will eventually run out of stack space and fail. A loop would be simpler and more correct.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the recursiveness limit! I forgot about that. Also, regarding on how I observe this, I'm telling it to print on the console the list information. In the beginning of the function there's something like print('starting the function'), and this repeats twice (each print followed by what the function does) and then it falls on the sleep function. Then it repeats.

Comment: You could probably find out if `__init__` is being called in two places by calling `traceback.print_stack()` at the start of `__init__`. If you get two different stack traces, you now know where it's being called twice. If you get just one, there must be something wrong with the way you create and run the thread. If you get the same one twice, perhaps something is causing your main.py to run twice.

Comment: Thanks Weeble, when you said 'something is causing your main.py to run twice' I remembered a Bottle feature I'm using. Bottle has an argument called 'reloader' that checks if the code has been changed, and then (duh) reloads the application. This is what was creating the other thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong thanks to the user Weeble's comment. When he said *'something is causing your main.py to run twice'* I remembered that Bottle has an argument that is called 'reloader'. When set to **True**, **this will make the application load twice**, and thus the thread creation is run twice as well.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
import threading
import time

class MyClass:
    def check_list(self, theList, arg1):
        keep_going=True
        while keep_going:
            print("check list")
            #do stuff
            time.sleep(1)

    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.a_list = ["1","2"]
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.check_list, args=(self.a_list, arg1))
        t.start()

myObject = MyClass("something")
```

Comment: Now what if I want to call this from main? I do myObject = MyClass(arg1), yes?

Comment: That's exactly what I do, yes. But if you're running an application, it might be better to call it in the `__init__` method of the app (but I really don't know how Bottle work)